# WordPress deletes custom posts instead of trash them

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, trash

I need to trash some **custom posts**, under certain conditions, via code (it's a plugin self-written)

The theme used is a children

I don't shutdown the ability to trash the post;

In config.php there is not set the constant `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` but in `default-constant.php` I can read

```
/**
 * Defines functionality related WordPress constants
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
function wp_functionality_constants() {
    /**
     * @since 2.5.0
     */
    if ( !defined( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL' ) )
        define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 60 );

    /**
     * @since 2.9.0
     */
    if ( !defined( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS' ) )
        define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 30 );

    if ( !defined('WP_POST_REVISIONS') )
        define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', true);

    /**
     * @since 3.3.0
     */
    if ( !defined( 'WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT' ) )
        define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 60);  // In seconds
}
```

From dashboard I can trash the custom posts and the single post and page, so trash (seems to me) to work.

But from my code if I select a post to trash, it will be deleted.

```
[...]

$temp = new \WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $temp->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $temp->have_posts() ) {

                $id_post = get_the_ID();

                wp_delete_post($id_post , false);


            }

        }

[...]
```

**If I try with wp_trash_post, posts are trashed and not deleted.**

Any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: Check the config.php file and be sure that `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` constant is not set to zero. Also, deactivate all plugins and activate a default theme and try your code again. Your code looks correct.

Comment: @cybmeta I'm using last version of WP, 4.9. The constant is not configured on config.php but it is present on default-constant.php (you can see in my post). I did try of course with base theme and no plugin other than mine.

Comment: Can you verify that `$id_post` is correct? In the way you are using `get_the_ID()`, you should do `$temp->the_post()` first. Can you share a full sample code that we can use directly to try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I did a mistake. If I try with wp_trash_post, posts are trashed. Custom Posts are totally deleted If I use wp_delete_post, also with "false" param.